# Netplan: Route multiple parallel internet connections with port forwarding to a single server with 1 network port

Tags: iptables, routing, iproute2, netplan

Here's my network diagram:

```
        56.56.56.56 192.168.0.1/24
                    MAC:AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:01
               ___________     
            ---| Modem 1 |-------
            |  ___________      |             ___________
Internet ---|               | Switch |--------| Machine |
            |  ___________      |             ___________
            ---| Modem 2 |-------            192.168.0.3/24
               ___________     
        67.67.67.67 192.168.0.2/24
                    MAC:AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:02
```

1. Both modems forward the same ports from the internet to the machine.
2. The machine behind the modems should respond appropriately to any request coming from the internet. e.g. Modem 1 packets return via Modem 1, Modem 2 packets return via Modem 2.
3. The machine has only one network port and the switch is unmanaged.
4. The machine uses [`Netplan`](https://netplan.io/), iptables, and iproute2 for network configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I eventually got my solution from article and comments in [Policy Routing on Linux based on Sender MAC Address](https://linuxmonk.ch/wordpress/index.php/2016/policy-routing-on-linux-based-on-sender-mac-address/) and the [Netplan.io reference on Policy-Routing](https://netplan.io/reference#routing).

The trick is to mark and CONNTRACK incoming packets by source MAC address to a separate routing table via `iptables -t mangle`, and then tell Netplan to use the table to route outgoing packets appropriately.

First, we need tables for our packets to be herded into:

Append the following to the file `/etc/iproute2/rt_tables`:

```
1 modem1
2 modem2
```

Then, tell Netplan about the tables, routes, and marks:

```
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      routes:
        - to: 0.0.0.0/0
          via: 192.168.0.1
          table: 1
        - to: 0.0.0.0/0
          via: 192.168.0.2
          table: 2
      routing-policy:
        - from: 0.0.0.0/0
          mark: 1
          table: 1
        - from: 0.0.0.0/0
          mark: 2
          table: 2
```

This first part tells `netplan` that packets in these different tables need different default routes.  The second part says that some packets will have an `fwmark` from iptables, and these packets should be herded into those tables.

Then, tell `iptables` to mark packets by their originating MAC address, but only when it's not from the local network (a little script):

```
#!/bin/bash -x
MAC_MODEM1=AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:01
MAC_MODEM2=AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:02
MARK_MODEM1=0x1
MARK_MODEM2=0x2
LOCALNET=192.168.0.0/24

## Optional - Clear everything first
iptables -t mangle -F

for MODEM in MODEM1 MODEM2; do
    MAC=MAC_$MODEM
    MARK=MARK_$MODEM
    iptables --table mangle --append INPUT \
    --match state --state NEW \
    --match mac --mac-source ${!MAC} \
    ! --source $LOCALNET \
    --jump CONNMARK --set-mark ${!MARK}
done
iptables --table mangle --append OUTPUT \
--jump CONNMARK --restore-mark
```

Then, tell netplan to generate and apply:

```
$ sudo netplan generate
$ sudo netplan apply
```

e voila!

**BONUS ANSWER**

If you have more than one internal network (e.g. a VPN via a non-local IP), use `ipset` and `iptables` `-m set ! -match-set alias`, e.g.

```
ipset destroy officenets #optional - to clear

LOCALNET=192.168.0.0/24
VPNNET=10.10.10.0/29

ipset create privatenets hash:net
ipset add privatenets $LOCALNET
ipset add privatenets $VPNNET
```

then in the iptables script....

```
    iptables --table mangle --append INPUT \
    --match state --state NEW \
    --match mac --mac-source ${!MAC} \
    -m set \
    ! --match-set privatenets src \
    --jump CONNMARK --set-mark ${!MARK}
```

**Verification**

Verify fwmark rules to route tables:

```
$ ip rule
0:  from all lookup local 
0:  from all fwmark 0x1 lookup modem1 
0:  from all fwmark 0x2 lookup modem2 
32766:  from all lookup main 
32767:  from all lookup default
```

Verify iptables mangle routing:

```
$ sudo iptables -t mangle -L
...
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
CONNMARK   all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW MAC AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:01 ! source 192.168.0.1/24 CONNMARK set 0x1
CONNMARK   all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW MAC AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:02 ! source 192.168.0.2/24 CONNMARK set 0x2

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
CONNMARK   all  --  anywhere             anywhere             CONNMARK restore
...
```

Verify outgoing table routes:

```
$ ip route list table modem1
default via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0 proto static
$ ip route list table modem2
default via 192.168.0.2 dev eth0 proto static
```